# r: fix function variable naming and use transmute

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I created a custom function that ingests three separate variables:

```
dblExponential<- function(a, b, x){
  # Prepare result data frame
  result_df <- data.frame(x)
  # loop through the sequence
  for (i in a) {
    for (j in b){
      # Compute column for value i
      result_column <- j^(i^(x/max(x)*100))
      # Define name of column in the resulting data frame
      result_column_name <- as.character(paste(x, i, j, sep = "_"))
      # Add the column to the data frame
      result_df[result_column_name] <- result_column
    }
  }
  # Return the result data frame
  return(result_df)
}
```

I want to run the below data frame through it:

```
dfTest<- data.frame(rnorm(10,13,3), rnorm(10, 12, 2))
colnames(dfTest)<- c("var1", "var2")

# creating a & b per the function above
alpha<- seq(0.85, 0.95, by= .01)
beta<- sapply(1:10, function(x){.1**x})

# run function
dfTest2<- dblExponential(alpha, beta, dfTest)
```

When I pass `dfTest` directly through the function, I get 220 variables I want (each `var` run through the 11 values for alpha, 10 for beta), however, the names are listed out in the format below:

```
c(7.74041000068398, 17.0484482255766, 14.3454072552564, 
11.9569186059367, 15.8419904194506, 20.8602917396248, 11.8515604771538, 
10.5655772517175, 13.32365521973, 15.9976857032445)_0.95_1e-08
```

What do I need to change in the `paste` function to adjust this?

Further, I'm trying to figure out if this is worth using `dplyr` at all, and when i try to run it through transmute I get a different error:

```
dfTest3<- dfTest %>% 
  transmute_all(funs(sCurve(alpha, beta, dfTest)))
```

It returns the below error:

```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  > Column `var1` is of unsupported class data.frame
```

I'd like to know how to use both for flexibility.

Comment: I am not sure of what you are trying to do but as the first code line of the function write `xnames <- names(x)` then, inside the inner loop, `result_column_name <- paste(xnames, i, j, sep = "_")`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas this worked for when I run the full dataframe through the function, but for some reason if I try to designate only `dfTest$var1`, the headers do not take the variable name (they look like this: `_0.85_0.1` any idea why the different when I provide the dataframe vs. the single variable?